# Problems formatting dates with Dygraphs

Tags: javascript, date, dygraphs

I am plotting data from a CSV files with Dygraphs. The dates are UNIX timestamps.

Currently I am parsing and formatting the dates like this:

```
    ...
    axes: {
      x : {
        valueFormatter: Dygraph.dateString_,
        ticker: Dygraph.dateTicker
      }
    },
    ...
```

Here are the first lines of a typical CSV file:

```
x,ATLAS.HLTSV.AvailableCores.DF.HLTSV.Events
1392052678784,0.0
1392052703784,0.0
1392052708784,30.0
1392052713784,845.0
1392052718784,1313.0
1392052723784,1313.0
1392052728784,1431.0
...
```

This gives me the following result:

[image: graph]

**The rendered dates are correct, but I have 2 problems**

- First the dates are too long, and clearly break the graph layout.
- Second the granularity is fixed. I would like it to changed based on the zoom level, such as in this example: http://dygraphs.com/tests/demo.html

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you share a link to a demo? I'm having trouble imagining why that would happen. Also, the values you set for ticker and valueFormatter should be the default. Why are you setting them?

Comment: @danvk Regarding the values for `ticker` and `valueFormatter`: if I don't set them, then the timestamps are displayed without any formatting! like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/n9jmz.png. Setting `axisLabelFontSize: 13` fixed the y-label formatting, it's not cut anymore. The problem remains for the y-axis. I added a sample from the CSV format, I'll extract a demo from the application if it doesn't clear up things enough...

Comment: I meant the problem remains for the *x-axis*, ie the dates are still way too long and break the layout.

Comment: that's a screenshot, not a demo. Please send one based on dygraphs.com/fiddle.

Comment: Did you solve the timestamp issue? I'm seeing the same thing myself.

Comment: In case someone else comes across this in the future: the solution is to format the date server side. Instead of feeding Dygraphs with timestamps directly, pass it "Y-m-d H:i:s" strings for the date field, and the time label will become short and readable in the final graph. This also means if you want the data source to be a csv file you have to pre-process it server side first.

Comment: @Mahn please make your comment an answer so I can accept it...

Comment: @MasterScrat will do, I figured you'd found a workaround in the meantime since the question had months when I came across it.

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't find how to format dates client-side in the original scenario you describe, a workaround that seems to work well is to format the dates server side first. Instead of feeding Dygraphs with timestamps directly, pass it "Y-m-d H:i:s" strings for the date field, and the time label will become short and readable in the final graph. This also means if you want the data source to be a csv file you have to pre-process it server side first.